# Why is the sum of an int and a float an int?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
float d  = 3.14f;
int   i  = 1;
auto sum = d + i;
```

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), `i` should be converted to `float` when it is added to `d`. However, when I actually run the code, I find that `sum` is 4. Why does this happen?

Interestingly, when I explicitly put my compiler into C11 mode, I found that `sum` was 4.14. What rules does the C11 standard change that affect the outcome?

What would happen if I compiled the same code using a C++ compiler?

Comment: That depends on your C++ version, before C++11 `auto` was the keyword for automatic storage, so `sum` defaulted to `int`. That would also be the case if you use C, which you originally tagged.

Comment: The **tl;dr** comment: post a [mcve]. There is no meaningful way to explain what **you did wrong** without seeing it. I assure you it's not a problem with the language or compiler.

Comment: What C++ compiler did you compile this with?  It doesn't compile [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0247cbfef8c8b0d8) unless you use C++11 and if you do [you get a float](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d0545970710d88a).

Comment: @mch It was an error before C++11, C++ does not have implicit `int`.

Comment: Please [discuss this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354181/2371524).

Comment: @mch: C++ never supportted the "implicit int" rule. So before C++11 `sum` did not "default to `int`" as you incorrectly stated in the comment. Before C++11 `auto sum` was simply invalid.

Comment: @Felix None of the other mods have wanted to touch this one, so I'm finally getting around to processing your flag. :-) I disagree that it is "very clear" the OP was looking for the C++11 meaning of `auto`. Note that the cppreference.com article he links to is for the *C* language and doesn't even mention automatic type deduction in the C++11 sense. However, I take your point that there have been a lot of absurd edits here, so I've tried to rewrite it in a way that preserves the spirit and is consistent with the answers it has received. Hopefully that is acceptable to you.

Comment: Hi @CodyGray, it's close to the original state, so I guess it's fine. My argument is the *misconception* of the OP once *was* obvious (and now, it's obvious again) because the *expected* behavior seems to have been that of C++11. Oh well...

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In C (and C++), `3.14f + 1` is a `float` type due to *type promotion* of `int` to `float`.

**But** in C, up to and including C90, and such a standard may well possibly be your C compiler default, this is assigned to an `int` type, yielding 4, since `int` is the default type for a variable with automatic storage duration. From C99 onwards, compilation will fail as implicit int was withdrawn, although compilers might still permit it, with a warning.

(In C++11 and later, `auto` instructs the compiler to deduce the type. `sum` will be a `float` with value `3.14f + 1`.  Compiling as C++98 or C++03 may still work, but generate a warning about C++11 extensions.  [This is what clang does, for example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHIB6bgajQBbAA54ANpmJ9UwgnlQA7BiACkABgCCvPgFoAHsj5EBqEeMx8Ahgz4BhAHQCEqVAwuL3AMz591W/j66DAToKgDMACLIAJxqPjrBoZEx0fGJ4VG0tH7apoR8%2BcZCohJWNrYqAEwAQlXVjk4ubtIKXj45AWkhGch1ddEAHEHdyX01amHDSVFj1VlTPbO0ACwLozV1tABefn54CgQFBySeYqiWBAD6lsxEAG6WxBB3qHjoAJS7AOy1moHoLAARqV0L5InwwvYVuFfhpAvtDngwRE%2BNkwrDAjdjAxmIJkXxQXUCjC/IFiJgCKwFHwGHgtphUJ4IDjBJ90T5tKtBJhLEojgRSHwhtzeTYAcxgZhvhFdpoEfyTmcLpdMHphOSGLTFM9Xh9vhifOLJQT8ZDoejST55UiMqiSX8fOTKcRqbT6YyIISagU2dUOfwuTy%2BQjBcKg2KgRJpX5OO9SGIuABWTikBRcNQp1BcCobb1MVjsXyVMK0FMEdOxuMAaxAibU8a4yxTac4GdIWc4KeU9fLrdjpDgsBgiBQphKknIlGK5mIKDEvOAyzU9c84gIkmUEEu27UlDjgIrpCE3IOAHkFGIAJ6H/Dk5ByO6YZR98gHTAJl9UACOzEk184kKVFCKYSAowAEEg9DqpgdynoCVCYPelDbpcu7MnSWwSLQda0AAbGoiZfAMuFZMslDMAoWCrq06CUBIwCYJR8CJqQ9acKW7ycXGoHgZBpDQbB8GIeWW47pQVAAIq/sQl5hJUtBqF8XyJtEYS4csynLsslTqQMtCUPgDDCPO/79m6mGYNhah4QRREkSs5GUZg1GYLRED0YxtGQCxbEcVx8aMbxdD%2BTIciKM%2B%2BiGAkIyZLQgS6AA6pYYhiLop5hF2LBsBwtDcUmzaHh2ejETo6kCPOYF8Ms9hqDVfAQLghAkEWJaCrYY4zi1uVlhWnGkAgPJYLOEB5ZwTakIIICVF89i4WEcmJsRagDAMXzRF8uGpoVXBdiAPa9QOw4QEgLAEMItyThA04SLO9CuU1t2jcmW0vh2VQlnwADuhAIHwxW4aVqzIBVwBVTVNU9X2fUDZYQ17g2Y0ppNKz2OtuEDGo2kDNpaiVMuXwvW2Ha7ftUOHfAx2jmYN2XddkhzguS4rmuG7IWJI2kAeL7HoxBDnleN54HeD5PoeCLvoe37Sf%2BgHAQFYEQXQ/HkoJCFIaJqGUOZWE4fhhHEaRjlUfsrl0ZgDFMZACmsaQ7GVn1PGK1BKtwWrIkoWhknS3JClKSpakaXWmM6csekGXgRkmTtcba5Zuu2QbDkQBRxs0WbFteRA1u%2Bfb3GBU7IWyPIShcNF0y9Lm1QTPFOhJSlaUZYwWXsMFCPPS2RNcP9gPlQuYO1XEDX4EQUjvfQdgdTdLWVO8kMZn1NZ1gj42TWEtUG2o0RbypAyJomoeE5mO2MHtpC9vP5OwCdtznQKFBXZP9OVKQ90j63H7t9tnDvZUX0/X9JUyrAz7tVAec9KzLyRlNXC9hEyVBWmEL4KwvhqFwtNTaHcj6dhPqTee1Zaz1g/I3TB7Zj7nwgR%2BSoBVXpkN6nGR8xAtRpmWEAA). This re-defining of `auto` in C++11 represents another material divergence between C and C++.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150634/discussion-on-answer-by-bathsheba-why-is-the-sum-of-an-int-and-a-float-an-int).

Comment: I tested with `double` instead of `float`, so `return sizeof(sum)` or `return sizeof(d+i)` would return a constant indicating the type (making it easy to look at compiler asm output: https://godbolt.org/g/PyoiRm), without needing to use an `auto` return type.  **`sum` is an `int` in C89/90, C99 and C11, according to gcc and clang.**  Your "up to C90" phrase doesn't seem right, unless it's actually different for `float` than `double`.  In C++ (98/03/11) `sum` is a `double`, so the redefinition of `auto` doesn't seem to have any effect here.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you have any explanation for this? Didn't `auto` mean the same thing (an explicit specifier for *automatic storage*) in C++ before C++11?

Comment: Of course, *implicit int* was only part of the oldest C standard, so the code is only well-defined for C *up to* C90 and for C++ *starting from* C++11, so I'd say the answer is correct, but you can't be sure what compilers using other standards make of that code.

Comment: Yes, we went round the houses on this yesterday - see the comments the mods (appropriately) moved to chat.

Comment: That's because the code is actually malformed in C99 and C11, @Peter. GCC and Clang default to being compatible with C89/C90, where `sum` is an `int` because of the implicit-int rules, and that's what you observe in the disassembly. If you look at the output, you'll see that they do issue a diagnostic (although it is only a warning). Nothing changes for `double` vs. `float`. There was, as mentioned, a discussion about this previously, with references to the standard text, but it got lost in a bunch of noise and was moved to chat. And people say there's nothing wrong with this question!

Comment: @CodyGray The "need" to discuss this doesn't automatically make the question flawed, because the facts are still quite clear. But please let's have **this** discussion [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354181/2371524), you're invited to write your arguments there, thank you.

Comment: @CodyGray: d'oh, I missed the warning.  This answer should more clearly say that `auto sum` isn't valid C99/C11.  I thought that "quite possibly your C compiler default" was talking about whether your compiler defaulted to C90 or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes: that's exactly what I meant. I've amended the answer slightly. My aim was to keep this answer easy to read but embed some technical depth at the same time. Perhaps a more standards orientated answer will emerge - I invite anyone to borrow as much as they want from this answer.

Comment: I think it would be a lot better to explicitly say something about C99/C11, at least 1 sentence or phrase.  And also about C++ before C++11, since `clang -std=c++03` warns that `'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`.  Your answer just says "in C++".

Answer (score 5):

It's rather simple really.

In old versions of C (before C99), you could write something like

```
auto n = 3;
```

and `n` would be an `int` type with the value 3. You could also write

```
auto n = 3.14f;
```

and `n` would *still* be an `int` type, with a value 3.

This was called *implicit int* and K & R made it quite famous.

So can you see that

```
auto sum = d + i;
```

merely assigns the `float` type `d + i` to `sum` which is an implicit `int`.

Hence the answer 4.

In newer versions of C (C99 onwards), implicit int was dropped.

Comment: In other words, in C `auto n = 3.14f` is just shorthand for `auto int n = 3.14f`. Someone had to say it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In some compilers, files with a `.c` extension are compiled as C, not C++.

```
float d = 3.14f;
int i = 1;
auto sum = d + i;
```

compiled as:

```
float d = 3.14f;
int i = 1;
int sum = d + i;
```

In the C language, `auto` is a keyword for specifying a storage duration. When you create an `auto` variable it has an “automatic storage duration”. We call these objects “local variables”. In C, all variables in functions are local by default. That’s why the keyword `auto` is hardly ever used.

The `auto` keyword is useless in the C language. It is there because before the C language there existed a B language in which that keyword was necessary for declaring local variables. (B was developed into NB, which became C.)