# Why is an addition of a float and int results a float?

Tags: c, clang

I'm currently reading "The C Programming Language - 2nd Edition". In the first chapter, it is explained that an operation of an float with an int results an int. There is this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper)
    {
        celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);
        printf("%3.0f\t%6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

When the line `fahr = fahr + step` is executed, shouldn't `fahr` become an int ? Does it stays a float because I was declared as a float ?

Comment: I think you must have misread. When you combine float and int, the int is converted to float, not the other way around.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416000/why-is-the-sum-of-an-int-and-a-float-an-int) may be relevant.

Comment: Variables can't change type in C.

Comment: OT: regarding: `celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);`  the variables (celsius, fahr) have type `float`, but the literals (5.0, 9.0, 32.0) have type `double`  A much better way is to declare the literals as type `float` by appending a `f` to the end of each literal,  I.E. `celsius = (5.0f/9.0f) * (fahr-32.0f);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you declared your variable as a float, it won't change in your code. If you do an operation between an int and a float and put on a float variable, you will have a float result, and the opposite is true, if you put your variable in a int var, you will lose the decimal part of your number.

You can't change your variable type in C.

Comment: However, in the actual code the compiler will promote the `int` to `float` while performing the actual calculation

Answer (score 0):

If the book said that, it is wrong. Simple as that!

When you add an integer to a float, you get a float. Furthermore, you assigned the result to a float, so it can't be anything else. Objects don't change type.

Comment: Can we speak about "objects" in C ?

Comment: @EconoMix Yes, same as C++. See section 3.14 of the standard (C99 reference).

Comment: @EconoMix It's not the kind of object you are thinking of, though.

Comment: @EconoMix: An object in C is a region of storage whose contents can represent values. For example, for `int x`, `x` is the name of four bytes of storage that can hold an `int` value (presuming the size of `int` is four). Those four bytes are an object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare `fahr` as a `float`, any value you assign to it will be converted to `float`.

Any arithmetic operation between an `int` and a `float` will have a `float` result.  This is specified as part of the *usual arithmetic conversions*:

> #### 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
> types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
> and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. Unless
> explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
> the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
> and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*:
>
> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other
> operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other
> operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
> corresponding real type is `double`.
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other
> operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
> corresponding real type is `float`.<sup>62)</sup>
> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
> following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
> integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
> converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
> equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
> signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
> integer type.
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
> all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
> the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with signed integer type.
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
> corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>62) For example, addition of a `double _Complex` and a `float` entails just the conversion of the
> `float` operand to `double` (and yields a `double _Complex` result).</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

An arithmetic operation between two `int`s will yield an `int` result.  For example, `1/2` yields `0`, `4/3` yields `1`, `7/3` yields `2`, etc.  If you assign the result of an integer division to a `float` variable, it will be stored as a `float`, but you don't get the fractional portion of the result.  IOW, given code like

```
float fahr = 4 / 3;
printf( "%f\n", fahr );
```

your output will be `1.0`, not `1.33333`.  If you want a floating-point result, at least one of the operands must be a floating-point type:

```
float fahr = 4 / 3.0f;
printf( "%f\n", fahr );
```

will output `1.33333`.

Answer (score -3):

+1 For reading that book.
C chooses the highest resolution on arithmic, so float wins in your case.

Comment: 32-bit `float` is not higher resolution than 32-bit `int`.